# leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt doesn't work if editing is set to true

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently trying to implement a table view according to the following design:

[image]

I need to be able to delete rows in the table view using a leading swipe action and I need to be able to move the rows around with the hamburger icon.

I implemented the leading swipe using the `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method and I implemented the reorder functionality by calling `setEditing` and implementing the `moveRowAt` delegate method.

Both work fine until put together. It seems that `setEditing` disables the swipe actions. I've tried out the various `tableView.allowXXXX` members, but they don't seem to fix this.

I also tried implementing the `canEditRowAt`, but this also didn't fix my issue.

At last I tried to search through the leading swipe action configuration interface, but I couldn't find anything that would help me.

Is this impossible to do with the standard components from UITableView or am I missing something?

Below is my code snippet:

```swift
import UIKit

class CScreensTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
        
        Model.shared.retrieveData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return createHeaderView(title: NSLocalizedString("metrics", comment: "Metrics"))
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 96
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Model.shared.getNrOfEntries()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Omitted cell creation for the purpose of this question. There are no tableview calls here
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        if sourceIndexPath.row != destinationIndexPath.row {
            Model.shared.moveScreen(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        model.didSelect(atIndex: indexPath.row)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action: UIContextualAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (_, _, completionHandler) in
            if Model.shared.tryDelete(withIndex: indexPath.row) {
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.middle)
            }
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        
        action.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .bold))?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        action.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
}
```

Comment: With your need for a non-standard swipe-to-delete it may be better to implement row movement using table view drag and drop instead of going into edit mode.

Comment: Thanks. Can you make this an answer to the question? I'll try it out and if it works approve your answer.